# Django prefetch_related a large dataset

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, query-optimization

I am right now having an issue with django's prefetch related.
To give an example, let's imagine those models

```
from django.db import models

class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Purchase(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client')
```

Let's imagine we have a few clients, something like 200, but they buy a lot so we have millions of purchases.

If I have to create a webpage displaying all the clients and the number of purchases for each client, I would have to write something like that

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
from .models import Purchase, Client

purchases = Purchase.objects.all()
clients = Client.prefetch_related(Prefetch('purchase_set', queryset=purchases))
```

The problem here is that I will query the big purchases database and that query might take even more than one minute, or worse create a MemoryError on the server.

So, I tried to select only a batch of that database with

```
 purchases = Purchase.objects.all()[:9]
```

but as we could expect, Django does not like it much and launches this kind of exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
 line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
 line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py",
 line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", l
ine 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.
py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", l
ine 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
****************** login decorators, views, ... 
  File "project/***.py", line ***, in ***
    for client in clients:
  File "project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", li
ne 258, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", li
ne 1076, in _fetch_all
    self._prefetch_related_objects()
  File "project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", li
ne 656, in _prefetch_related_objects
    prefetch_related_objects(self._result_cache, self._prefetch_related_lookups)
  File "project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", li
ne 1457, in prefetch_related_objects
    obj_list, additional_lookups = prefetch_one_level(obj_list, prefetcher, lookup, level)
  File "project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", li
ne 1556, in prefetch_one_level
    prefetcher.get_prefetch_queryset(instances, lookup.get_current_queryset(level)))
  File "project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/relate
d_descriptors.py", line 539, in get_prefetch_queryset
    queryset = queryset.filter(**query)
  File "project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", li
ne 790, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", li
ne 802, in _filter_or_exclude
    "Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken."
AssertionError: Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.
```

So right now, I have no real solution. I'm looking how the __iter__ function in django/db/models/query.py:258 is built to try to create a function with the same behaviour but requiring a limited set in the prefetch in order to page it, and do things in a more parallel way.

Is there any "good way" to do those kind of queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's imagine we have a few clients, something like 200, but they buy
>   a lot so we have millions of purchases.
>
> If I have to create a webpage displaying all the clients and the
>   number of purchases for each client, ...

I'm going to interpret your question as wanting this functionality.  Have you tried:

```
from django.db.models import Count
clients = Client.objects.annotate(num_purchases=Count('purchase'))
clients[0].num_purchases
```

If you want to sort and get the highest purchasing clients, you can also do:

```
clients = Client.objects.annotate(num_purchases=Count('purchase')).order_by('-num_purchases')[:5]
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/ for more functionality.